# python 3. logical error in checking if a number is prime

Tags: python-3.x

in my program for finding a prime number, only the else statement gets displayed,even if the user enters a prime number. is there a problem in my if else statement? or in some mathematical operator? i have tried to indent it properly by python syntax. and please rectify the code.

```
    num=int(input("enter a number  :    "))
    ctr=0
    i=1
    for i in range(1,num):
        if(num%i==0):
             ctr+=1

    if(ctr==2):
        print(num," is prime")

    else:
        print(num," is not prime")
```

Comment: Change `if (ctr == 2)` to `if (ctr == 1)`. You can delete the line that says `i = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user enters a prime for `n`, it is only divisible by 1 and itself.  But `range(1,n)` never gets to `n`, so `ctr` is 1 for prime numbers, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble, try using the following function:

```
def isprime(number):
    if number == 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(number**0.5)+1):
        if number%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

To use it type `isprime(number)` and replace `number` with the number which you want to check.